# TCP out of memory

Tags: apache-2.4, tcp

I'm running one gcloud g1-small instance with Debian to power one Node server and one Apache server. I use Node Bouncy to redirect http requests to Node or Apache depending on `req.headers.host`. Each of my two websites are low-traffic, below 10k accesses a day.

After about two weeks running ininterruptly, both my Apache and Node websites stopped responding. I couldn't connect to the instance via SSH either. After rebooting and examining the logs, I found the following:

```
/var/log/kern.log:
kernel: [timestamp] TCP: out of memory -- consider tuning tcp_mem
(multiple times)

/var/log/apache2/error.log:
[Timestamp] [core:warn] [pid 573] (105)No buffer space available: AH00056: connect to listener on 0.0.0.0:8001
(multiple times)
```

There was nothing in my Node log file.

How can I prevent this error from happening again?

Comment: Have you checked the values in `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_mem`? Also, [man tcp(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp), `tcp_mem` section.

Comment: I've got: `net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 38910        51880   77820`

Comment: Those are very small values. You need to increase them.

Comment: This max value of 77820 pages equals 304 MB. My instance has 1.7 GB of memory, and typically has 1.3 GB free (cache discounted). What would be reasonable values for tcp_mem in this machine?

Comment: That is really up to you to to tune. I can only point out the fact that those values are quite low. Try increasing those values (x2) and monitor the instance.

Comment: If you are running out of memory you can also consider upgrading the machine type with more memory. The steps to do so are mentioned on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance).

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? If so please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have increased some TCP values, allowing for more memory to be used. I have added these lines to the server's startup script:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_mem='116730 155640 233460'
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans='24576'
```

While this shouldn't solve the problem forever, it should buy me more uptime before the server crashes. I've been rebooting the server once a month and had no problems so far.

The real solution, though, would be fixing the memory leak that causes this problem in the first place.

Comment: Absent a fix, It might be worthwhile to periodically restart the service which is leaking RAM.  Could be either time based or be done when the used RAM reaches some threshold and stays there a while.  Time based restarts might fire unnecessarily, but let you time them to happen at a low traffic time.

Answer (score -1):

Recently we experienced an interesting production problem. This application was running on multiple AWS EC2 instances behind Elastic Load Balancer. The application was running on GNU/Linux OS, Java 8, Tomcat 8 application server. All of sudden one of the application instances became unresponsive. All other application instances were handling the traffic properly. Whenever the HTTP request was sent to this application instance from the browser, we were getting following response to be printed on the browser.

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

Let us see how we resolved this issue by assigning values for these properties in the server:

> net.core.netdev_max_backlog=30000
>   net.core.rmem_max=134217728
>   net.core.wmem_max=134217728
>   net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=8192
>   net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=4096 87380 67108864
>   net.ipv4.tcp_wmem=4096 87380 67108864

[TCP: out of memory — consider tuning tcp_mem](https://blog.gceasy.io/2019/08/28/tcp-out-of-memory-consider-tuning-tcp_mem/)